# How to find files that have a colon in the file name?

Tags: macos

We have a folder with lots of subfolders and files, some of which contain colons. These are not allowed to be uploaded to SharePoint so I'm trying to find a way to get a list of all the files that contain a colon so we can rename them.

Finder search doesn't work at all with a colon.

Terminal command `find / :` lists every single file and folder.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: macOS doesn't allow colons in file names. Colon is a directory indicator `folder:file`. Don't use them, like you don't use these either - https://www.mtu.edu/umc/services/websites/writing/characters-avoid/ If you're trying to find it in Finder, search `folder/file` instead. It's a legacy swap because of differences between the unix underpinnings & the GUI.

Comment: `find / :` lists every single file and directory because it's almost equivalent to `find /; find :`. I have no experience whatsoever with macOS, but knowing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13298479/10765659) I expect `find /` to print every pathname, even if internally the filesystem uses `:` as separators. To find files with `:` in names (which internally may use `/` instead, depending on the filesystem) you need `find / -name '*:*'`. I'm posting this as a comment, not an answer, because I totally haven't tested on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments on my other "answer" (which was just too complex for a regular comment), user wants to find and rename files with unusual/troublesome characters in it.  Below is an old Perl script which can *find* files at any level below any dir, including with special chars.

You run it like this if you're trying to remove a char that needs to be escaped in a regex: `findfile.pl "\*"`

You can optionally add a dir at the end too, like `findfile.pl "\*" /opt`

If you're trying to rename files with a ":" (which I can't reproduce), I don't think you need to escape the colon, but I can't test this without files with colons.

Since the user wants to rename the files, just modify the print in the final line to rename according to requirements.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $substring;
my $dir;

if ($#ARGV < 0) {
  print "\nUSAGE: $0 <substring> [dir]\n\n";
  print "The substring is compared against the names of files located\nin (or under) dir (which is \".\" if not specified).\n";
  print "\nPlease enter the substring: ";
  $substring = <>;
  chomp $substring;
  print "Please enter the directory: [.] ";
  $dir = <>;
  chomp $dir;
  if ($dir eq "") { $dir = "." }
}
else {
  $substring = $ARGV[0];
  if ($#ARGV > 0) {
    $dir = $ARGV[1];
  }
  else {
    $dir = ".";
  }
}

find(sub {if (m/$substring/i) {print "$File::Find::name\n"}}, $dir);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I posted another answer with what I did, but yours is more accurate for my initial question. I've not tested this as I don't own a Mac. Just an observation, with your last if statement, wouldn't it match every sub file and folder if the parent folder contains the substring we're looking for? If we were looking for `ABC`, would it match for example: `/folder/ABC/file1`, `/folder/ABC/some other file.docx`, `/folder/ABC/some subfolder/another one/a file.xlsx`?

Comment: Good observation, I had to go check that. It does NOT match every file in a sub-folder if the folder’s name has the special char. But, the folder itself does show up in the output list. Anyway, glad you found your one-liner solution!

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I wanted to remove these special characters from the folder and file names. I ended up installing xcode and homebrew along with the homebrew 'rename' component. This ultimately allowed me to use a one liner for each character.

1. Open terminal and run `xcode-select –install`
2. Follow the prompts to install it.
3. Download HomeBrew (https://brew.sh/) by putting the below in terminal (password required):
   `curl -fsSL -o install.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh`
4. Install using `/bin/bash install.sh`
5. Install 'rename' using `brew install rename`
6. Use cd and ls and locate the folder you want to do the renaming on
7. This command will look for the word 'foo' and rename it with ‘bar’.
   `find . -exec rename -s 'foo' 'bar' {} +`

Once this is done, I used the following to rename the special characters (which are not supported by OneDrive).

```
find . -exec rename -s '"' '2' {} +
find . -exec rename -s '*' '8' {} +
find . -exec rename -s ':' '-' {} +
find . -exec rename -s '<' '(' {} +
find . -exec rename -s '>' ')' {} +
find . -exec rename -s '?' '' {} +
find . -exec rename -s '/' '_' {} +
find . -exec rename -s '\' '-' {} +
find . -exec rename -s '|' '-' {} +
find . -exec rename 's/^ *//' * {} + #remove leading blank spaces
find . -exec rename 's/ *$//' * {} + #remove trailing blank spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

The Finder does not allow you to create files with a colon.  You get this error:
[image: error]

If you use the Terminal to create a file with a colon, it shows up with a "/" in the Finder:

[image: slash]

Please modify your question with a picture of your files in the Finder and/or the Terminal, so we can try to recreate and help you.

Comment: Thanks, It's some clients data we're migrating to SharePoint. It may just be folders with this in the name.

Comment: I’d like to help, but I can’t reproduce this. Using macOS and Windows, I can’t create files or folders with a colon in the name. Can you provide a screenshot?  Maybe if we see the filenames (blur out parts if you need to), something will pop out.

Comment: Substitute `:` with `*` instead. I don't know how they named some files and folders with colon, but really all I want to do is rename every file that contains certain special characters, such as `* / \ [ ] < >`